# Double underline, one of them dashed

Tags: text-formatting, word-processing

Anyone knows **any** word processor that can do a double underline; one normal line and the other a dashed line?

*preferably a linux-native*

something similar to this:

[image: sample]

It's also fine if the dashed line is the top one.

Comment: Most word processors include line-drawing, which you can use to achieve this effect.

Comment: That's how I work it around but I need it to be "text underlining". ty @AFH

Comment: In that case, you need a font with the required double-underline: you may have to design it yourself. Again the word processor is immaterial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### LaTeX can do that. And *much more*.

Try it out with [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com), it's free.

When you have a LaTeX setup working, try this code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{\specdash{Some Text}}
\author{\specdashtwo{Author}}
\date{\specdashthree{20 October 2016}}

\newcommand{\specdash}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
        \draw[densely dashed] ([yshift=-2pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\specdashtwo}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[loosely dashed] ([yshift=-1pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-1pt]todotted.south east);
        \draw ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\specdashthree}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[dotted] ([yshift=-1pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-1pt]todotted.south east);
        \draw[densely dashed] ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
```

Here's a screenshot of the output of the above code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SU. When I read the question, the answer ,,LaTeX can probably do that'' immediately came to my mind. So thank's for the proof. For all others interested in this great typesetting system, please consider to visit the appropriate SE Site: [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com)